# Why can I not migrate a supply in a whenever block of a unix socket?

Tags: raku

server

```
#!/usr/bin/env raku

unlink "/run/user/1000/sock";
my $socket = IO::Socket::Async.listen-path("/run/user/1000/sock");

react {
  my $timerSupplier = Supplier.new;

  whenever $timerSupplier.Supply.migrate {
    say "3 second interval: ", $_;
  }
  $timerSupplier.emit(Supply.interval(3));

  whenever $socket -> $conn {
    $timerSupplier.emit(Supply.interval(3));
    say "\"", $_.Supply.lines.Channel.receive, "\"";
    $conn.close;
  }
}
```

client

```
#!/usr/bin/env raku

my $sock = IO::Socket::Async.connect-path("/run/user/1000/sock").result;
await $sock.print("ok\n");
```

If I execute server and then client, I get the following exception.

```
Unhandled exception in code scheduled on thread 8
Can only cancel an AsyncTask handle
  in block  at ./server line 16
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replacing

```
  whenever $socket -> $conn {
    $timerSupplier.emit(Supply.interval(3));
    say "\"", $_.Supply.lines.Channel.receive, "\"";
    $conn.close;
  }
```

with

```
  whenever $socket -> $conn {
    $timerSupplier.emit(Supply.interval(3));
    say "\"", $conn.Supply.lines.Channel.receive, "\"";
    $conn.close;
  }
```

fixed the error. It seems if a block has a named parameter, the topic variable stops working.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, it was a bug in your code. To find it I had to rewrite it a bit:

```
unlink "/run/user/1000/sock";
my $socket = IO::Socket::Async.listen-path("/run/user/1000/sock");

react {
  my $timerSupplier = Supplier.new;

  whenever $timerSupplier.Supply.migrate {
    CATCH { default { .message.say } }
    say "3 second interval:", $_;
  }

  $timerSupplier.emit( Supply.interval(3) );

  whenever $socket -> $conn {
    CATCH { default { .message.say } }

    $timerSupplier.emit(Supply.interval(3));
    say "\"{ $conn.Supply.lines.Channel.receive }\"";
    $conn.close;
  }
}
```

This allowed me to get past the error message, which is unhelpful at best. This change netted the following error message:

```
Cannot unbox a type object (Any) to a str.
```

So I had to change the first `whenever` block to the following:

```
  whenever $timerSupplier.Supply.migrate {
    CATCH { default { .message.say } }
    say "3 second interval: { $_ }";
  }
```

Which resulted in a working example:

```
3 second interval: 0
3 second interval: 1
"ok"
3 second interval: 0
3 second interval: 1
3 second interval: 2
```

My only suggestion is that you use string interpolation as much as possible, since that has the benefit of running an implied .Str() on the object in question. The semantics of `say $_` vs `say "{ $_ }"` are subtle, but profound.

Comment: in this bailiwick, you can also use the various quoting constructs to help out so eg ```say "\"{ $conn.Supply.lines.Channel.receive }\"";``` can be cast as ```say qq|"{ $conn.Supply.lines.Channel.receive }"|;```

Comment: or some may like ```~$conn.Supply.lines.Channel.receive;``` (the ~ is short idiom for .Str)

Comment: I do not understand why I got `Can only cancel an AsyncTask handle` in the first place. What does `CATCH { default { .message.say } }` do?

Comment: After runing `diff -u`, I discovered that replacing `$_.Supply.lines.Channel.receive` with `$conn.Supply.lines.Channel.receive` in the original code fixed the code.

Comment: It seems if a block has a named parameter, then the topic variable stops working.